# TicTacToe is cheating

Tags: objective-c, random, tic-tac-toe

I've created a TTT game.  However I'm having trouble with the AI taking spots.  How do I avoid this from happening so that in the `chooseCellRow:Col` method it only returns a random spot that has not already been selected by either player?

```
- (void) chooseCellRow:(NSInteger)row Col:(NSInteger)col
{
    //pick random spot for computer's turn
    row = random()%2;
    col = random()%2;

        if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
            [but00 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }
        else if (row == 0 && col == 1) {
            [but01 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }
        else if (row == 0 && col == 2) {
            [but02 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }

        else if (row == 1 && col == 0) {
            [but10 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }
        else if (row == 1 && col == 1) {
            [but11 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }
        else if (row == 1 && col == 2) {
            [but12 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }

        else if (row == 2 && col == 0) {
            [but20 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }
        else if (row == 2 && col == 1) {
            [but21 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }
        else if (row == 2 && col == 2) {
            [but22 setTitle:@"X" forState:0];
        }
}
```

Comment: do{
     row = random()%3;
     col = random()%3;
} while ((cell[row][col] != 'x') || (cell[row][col] != 'o'));

Comment: jsollo, see my comment in my answer, you should be using `&&` rather than `||`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheating is a moral concept, one which doesn't apply to the computer since it's doing exactly what you've told it to do. However, *you* could prevent this by simply choosing again if the cell is already occupied, pseudo-code:

```
row = random() % 3;
col = random() % 3;
while cell[row][col] != empty:  # Add your REAL detection code here.
    row = random() % 3;
    col = random() % 3;
```

You'll also notice that the above code stops *you* from cheating as well. Shame on you for only allowing the computer to choose four of the nine possibilities :-)

Applying `% 2` to a number will give you `0` or `1`, you need to use `% 3` to allow for `2` as well.

---

Based on your comments that you have a cell array which contains the character occupying that cell, the code to continuse until you find a blank cell would be along the lines of:

```
do {
    row = random() % 3;
    col = random() % 3;
} while (cell[row][col] != ' ');
```

Comment: Please see my comment under my O.P.  This is what I was trying to do however why would this prevent my simulator from running.  If I comment out the do/while than it runs (although I still have the same original problem)

Comment: @jsollo2, that's because you used `||` (or) in your expression. Think about it. A value _has_ to be either not-x or not-o since it can only be one thing at a time. If it's blank, you get true-or-true which is true. If x, false-or-true gives true and, if o, true-or-false gives true. Only if it x and o at the same time will your expression evaluate to false and the loop exit. You need to use `&&` (and).

Comment: Beginners mistake.  Thanks.  The simulator is still not running when I add the do/while though.

Comment: @jsollo2, you _do_ have a `cell` array, yes. If not, that was pseudo-code just meant to indicate how to do it. If the only place you store the cell content is on `butXY.title`, that's probably what you'll need to check rather than my (fictional) array.

Comment: @jsollo2, added a proper check, I had the sense reversed in my original suggestion. Use the logic in the answer rather than my comments.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to keep a list of unused positions and choose from that list. When either player moves, remove the position they choose from the list.

Another, even simpler but less efficient way is to have it choose any position, but try again if the spot it picks is already occupied.